# Why does pushoverr::pushover() inconsistently reach time limit?

Tags: r, pushover

I have a script that loops some code across about 200 iterations. Each iteration takes about two minutes to complete, and each iteration ends with a push message using `pushoverr::pushover()`. Occassionally, the push message is not sent and I instead receive the following error in the console:

```
Error in .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, enc2utf8(url), handle, nonblocking) : 
  reached elapsed time limit
```

The error occurs only on my virtual machine and not my local laptop. The virtual machine has 16GB RAM, and I log the RAM usage every minute using `free` on Ubuntu. In the logs, I see that "free RAM" is occassionally close to 0, but "available RAM" has consistently more than 10GB available at any time. Hence, although I have the impression from the error message this error could be caused from lack of memory, that is not the case.

Hence, does anyone have an idea what the reason for this error is and how to resolve it so that I consistently send push notifications without errors?